# "Drôle de" can be used sarcastically?

Tags: expressions

« Vous refusez ? Vous êtes sérieux ? **Drôle de** notion de l'amitié ! »

I suppose that the speaker means: "What an incredible notion of friendship you have!". The phrase "drôle de" meaning "incredible/terrific" can be used sarcastically?

Comment: Tout à fait : "Drôle d'oiseau celui-là !"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Drôle can have two meanings depending on the context : the most common one is "amusant, comique", and a less used one is "bizarre, curieux". I would translate drôle in this sentence by "weird" or "strange".

This second meaning is often implied by the use of "un drôle de" + noun.To answer your question, not only "drôle de" can be used sarcastically but it is specifically used to suggest a sarcastic meaning.

Un homme drôle : a funny guy /
Un drôle d'homme (or better : un drôle de bonhomme): a strange guy

Comment: Bel exemple ! ;)

Comment: I totally agree that putting *drôle* before or after changes the meaning; I'd have put that example if I'd thought of it :)

Answer (score 3):

I would translate your sentence as

> Funny notion of friendship you have there!

In fact I wonder where you got the translation "drôle de" as meaning "incredible/terrific". "Drôle" means "funny", amusing, and is is quite often used sarcastically, just as in English.

Comment: "In fact" or "Actually" ? :)

Comment: @Law29 Quant à « D'où provient l'idée de le sens "incredible/terrific" ? », j'ai cru le tenir de bonne source. Peut-être que cette définition n'est pas tout à fait correcte, après tout ? http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/dr%C3%B4le

Comment: The examples are good, in these cases you would translate by (for example) *incredible* . . . remembering that *incredible* means *cannot be believed*, or in these cases perchance *almost too bizarre to be believed* . . . translation is a funny business!